# Using Twigs "defined" test within my own Test

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong, but I'll ask anyway.

I am frequently writing the following throughout my Twig code:

```
{% if someVariable is defined and someVariable is not empty %}...{% endif %}
```

So I thought I'd write my own [test](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tests) that essentially does the same thing, only more refined:

```
$myOwnTest = new Twig_SimpleTest('myOwnTest', function ($value) {
    return isset($value) && !empty($value);
});
$twig->addTest($myOwnTest);
```

The above does work, but not in the same way as Twig's '[defined](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html)' test. So I was wondering if it's possible to use Twigs 'defined' test, within my own? Or perhaps there is another way of getting the same results?

Thanks

Comment: with symfony2 or craft?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I was meant to refactor that for Symfony2. I am working in Craft, but felt I'd get a better response from this community. I have edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with `in the same way as Twig's 'defined' test`? You'd prolly could get access to the core extensions if you define your test with the options `needs_environment`

Comment: I guess it's more down to my understanding on syntax and what I can actually do with "tests". I suppose what I'm really asking for is; what is the Twig equivalent of writing ```is defined``` in PHP? As PHP's ```defined(...)``` function doesn't do the same as thing.

Comment: You can see the PHP source of the `defined` test [here](http://twigfiddle.com/qaqwsx), Seems it uses the `getAttribute` for arrays and object which can be found [here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/v1.16.2/lib/Twig/Template.php#L358)

Comment: Thanks DarkBee, haven't managed to trawl through all of that 'Template.php' file yet, but I can see the answer must be in there. I will feedback an answer once it's tried and tested.